# Is "The first place he went to was to his bed." a wrong sentence?

Tags: prepositions, ellipsis

> The first place he went to was **to** his bed.

My point is, is the second "to" superfluous in the sentence?

Comment: Are *to* required? *The first place he went was his bed!*

Comment: What about "The first place he went to was his office"?

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree. *to* is dropped if it's usual place especially *home*. *The first place he went was to his bed.* Still...it's not fulfilling. Good question. +1

Comment: The _second_ **to** is indeed superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They are all correct**: this is all a matter of flavor of the language, what you're trying to emphasise and what you're trying to imply. This is going to be heavily influenced by the context and the general pace of the text leading up to it.

Yes, in fact, @MaulikV is right in the comments, none of the "to"s are actually required.

All good sentences:

1. "The first place he went was his bed" 
   -- rather casual feel. fewer words. lighter
2. "The first place he went to was his bed" -- hanging preposition, feels informal.
3. "The first place he went was to his bed" -- feels stronger, with "to his bed" as the object
4. "The first place he went to was to his bed" -- hanging preposition + full bodied object feels more stern or full of intent.

Comment: *Preposition* rather than *participle*.

Comment: I never can get this 'preposition' and 'participle'